# mat-select-trigger doesn't work with cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have a mat-select field with images + text as items, which worked very well without virtual-scroll. But as I have many many images in the list, they were loaded all at once. To prevent this behaviour I am using the cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport. And it works well, except the fact, that the initial value is not selected (it worked with mat-select-trigger in the previous version). And the selection also disappears, if you resize the window.

Here my code. What can I do? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
<mat-select (openedChange)="openChange($event)">
              <mat-select-trigger>
                <img src="assets/{{selected[1]}}.svg" />
                + {{selected[0]}}
              </mat-select-trigger>
              <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="48" class="viewport">
                <mat-option *cdkVirtualFor="let i of items;templateCacheSize: 0" [value]="i" (onSelectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
                  <img src="assets//{{ i[1] }}.svg" />+ {{i[0]}}
                </mat-option>
              </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
            </mat-select>
```

```
  openChange($event: boolean) {
    if ($event) {
      const selectedIndex = this.items.findIndex(elem => elem[1] === this.selected[1]);
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort.scrollToIndex(selectedIndex);
      this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort.checkViewportSize();
    } 
  }
```

```
  onSelectionChange(change: MatOptionSelectionChange) {
    if (change.isUserInput) {
      this.selected = change.source.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution. I'll share it here even if I think this is more a workaround than a real solution.

In my case the issue was only for a `multiple` select. The `mat-trigger` was disappearing when I would scroll down "too far" that the selected `mat-option` is being recycled by the virtual scroll.

I found out that if the `mat-trigger` was disappearing because of this `ngSwitch` inside `mat-select.html`:

```
<div class="mat-mdc-select-value" [ngSwitch]="empty" [attr.id]="_valueId">
    <span class="mat-mdc-select-placeholder mat-mdc-select-min-line" *ngSwitchCase="true">{{placeholder}}</span>
    <span class="mat-mdc-select-value-text" *ngSwitchCase="false" [ngSwitch]="!!customTrigger">
      <span class="mat-mdc-select-min-line" *ngSwitchDefault>{{triggerValue}}</span>
      <ng-content select="mat-select-trigger" *ngSwitchCase="true"></ng-content>
    </span>
  </div>
```

From source: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/017a541d496bfaaeda2f1207b6e6247213361dd9/src/material/select/select.html#L6

In fact, when I scrolled too far the `empty` property became true. I think this was due to the fact that the `mat-option` are being recycled.

Anyway, in order to fix it I override the property `empty` on scroll like this:

```
@ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport)
public cdkVirtualScrollViewPort: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.scrollDispatcher
            .scrolled()
            .pipe(filter(scrollable => this.cdkVirtualScrollViewPort === scrollable))
            .subscribe(() => {
                Object.defineProperties(this.matSelect, {
                    empty: {
                        value: this.selectedValues.length <= 0,
                        writable: true
                    }
                });
            });
}
```

`selectedValues` is being updated on selection change like this:

```
public onSelectionChange(change: MatOptionSelectionChange): void {
        const value: T = change.source.value;
        const index = this.selectedValues.indexOf(value);

        if (index > -1) {
            this.selectedValues.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            this.selectedValues.push(value);
        }
    }
```